# How can i reduce the size of my Jupyter Notebook where i am analyzing a huge dataset and plotting using plotly?

Tags: python, optimization, jupyter-notebook, plotly

The size of my jupyter notebook at this moment is 417 MB. I am analyzing 7 huge csv files at the same time and plotting figures using plotly. I am fairly new to coding. Is it normal to create such huge notebooks?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Select the `Cell` -> then select `All Outputs` -> There you will find `Clear` option select that. And then save the file. This will reduce the size of your file (From MBs to kbs). It will also reduce the time to load the notebook next time you open it in your browser.